# How to get default analyzer of index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd set default analyzer for index with this definition:

```
"index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": 'simple'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but then I getting settings of this index with query
http://localhost:9200/test/_settings?pretty=true
I getting only this, nothing about analyzer:

```
 {
  "test" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1423575850265",
        "uuid" : "Ac8QSGWbTtSCG7ib4VpV3Q",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1040299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your index and try again. You definition should work. It is probable it didn't work because an index with the same name already existed.

Try the following code in your [SENSE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en)

```
DELETE test

POST test
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "default" : {
                    "type" : "simple"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

GET test/_settings
```

This code returned:

```
{
   "test": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1423576958602",
            "uuid": "0iKpaL8uSKOSFT-oI1TJoQ",
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "default": {
                     "type": "simple"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1040199"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Problem was with single quotes around 'simple', all should key/values should be in double quotes –  Maxim K.

The [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/) requires to use double quotes.

Comment: Same result. What version are you using? I use 1.4.2 and need remove { before "index" in POST request to get response {acknowledged: true}

Comment: Version 1.4.1. I used the exact code I wrote. It works with and without the "remove" on my instance of ES.
By "same result", do you mean that you still don't get the right settings?

Comment: Problem was with single quotes around 'simple', all should key/values should be in double quotes

Comment: Well observed @MaximK. I didn't realize that was the problem. :)